# Wordpress get category from description

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, posts

I want to get category id from a category description. I add categories and posts programmatically. My script add category if category doesn't exist. I change category name and slug from panel. So my script add category each time.
[image]

Like this:

```
$categoryDescription = 'bla bla';
$category = get_category_by_description($categoryDescription);
echo $category['name'];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please review the post [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't test this, but try adding the following function to the functions.php in your theme:

```
function get_category_by_description($categoryDescription) {
    global $wpdb;

    $res = $wpdb->get_results("
        select 
            t.slug 
        from 
            {$wpdb->prefix}terms t, 
            {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy tx 
        where 
            t.term_id = tx.term_id and 
            tx.description = '{$categoryDescription}'
    ");

    if (!empty($res)) {
        return get_category_by_slug($res[0]->slug);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
$categoryDescription = 'bla bla';
$category = get_category_by_description($categoryDescription);
echo $category->name;
```